# How to link Meschach library to a C program using Windows

Tags: c, matrix, linker, libraries, inverse

I am somewhat new to C programming (learned this summer) and am in a Linear Programming course at K-State.  My term project is to build a linear programming solver (interior point method, I'm doing the primal-dual path following algorithm).  I have everything coded up properly but cannot get an efficient matrix inverse calculation.  My professor advised I use an established C library of matrix calculations.  This led me to "Meschach12b", which I downloaded.

I looked up and learned how to link a directory and how to link a library.  I am using CodeBlocks and Windows 10, FYI.  I pointed CodeBlocks to the directory with the header files and then went to link the library but saw that there are no ".lib", ".so", or ".a" files in the folder I downloaded.  I don't know if I'm just missing it somehow, or if this can be done without those files.  I'm searching online 24/7 practically for a way to implement this into my algorithm because without it, my term project is useless!  This is due this week so any help would be appreciated!

More info:

-When I #include the header files I'm attempting to use, it "works" when I build until I call the function later.  Then an error pops up saying that there are tons and tons of "undefined references" (like 50+), but I'm only calling one function.  I'm sure that's due to my library not being linked properly.

-I searched through this site and found one person asking about Meschach and he claimed his library was "installed properly" and showed a screenshot of something where he typed "whereis libmeschach" or something like that.  I have no idea how to do that but it makes me assume that's what I'm missing!

-I'll post anything else I need to, but I'm desperate to be pointed in the right direction.  I've poured about 50 hours into this project and I don't want it to all be for naught.  :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you downloaded something like mesch12b.zip (from [meschach](http://homepage.math.uiowa.edu/~dstewart/meschach/)) you will need to build the library first.  The afore mentioned file seem to have a directory for MicroSoft, with a make-file included, although I have not attempted to build it on a Windows system (warning: it may not be trivial, sadly).

If you downloaded your copy of mescharc from somewhere else, edit your original post with the link and I take a look and see if I can help you.

Please note, I don't use CodeBlocks so what ever advise I can give you will be somewhat generic.  (now if you want to download either a community version of [visual studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs.aspx) *or* NtEmacs and [mingw-w64](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php), I can give much more detailed advise :) ).

Comment: If I use a different compiler, can I just copy my code into that and run it just fine?  I just happened to hear good things about CodeBlocks so I started there.  Also, I did downloaded mesch12b.zip from the website.  I saw a "make file" and the README file said to put that and the appropriate header.h in the Meschach directory, which I did.  I used the "GCC" folder - is this the correct one for Windows 10 laptop running an i7 processor?  I have a Sony VAIO Ultrabook.

Comment: @user297883: Normally you can switch compilers easily; however every compiler has its own quirks so on switching compiles you may get some compilation errors.  I would suggest using the makefile and the header.h file from the MicroSoft folder (seeing as how you are running a Windows platform).   Now the tricky part - the makefiles supplied with mesch12b are for the GNU Make utility; which you probably do not have unless you have installed Cygwin, or msys, or gnuwin32 or similar.  CodeBlocks may have the ability to import a make file and build a project from it.

Comment: @user297883: Thinking about it a bit more, your best bet might be to install a version of Linux in a VM, you will have access to all the normal development tools (gcc / make / g++, etc).  If your project code doesn't depend on Windows stuff (most notably GUI stuff), you should be able to move you code base over to a Linux VM and be able to recompile there with little effort.  THe good news is that CodeBlocks runs on Linux as well as Windows.  Also, the version of CodeBlocks that you download probably had gcc included, and gcc is the standard compiler on Linux.

Comment: This is very interesting - may I ask what benefit running CodeBlocks on Linux has?  Will that somehow make dealing with the "make file" easier?  I honestly have no problem downloading whatever compiler makes this work (if that's easier than running Linux on VM).  I've tried everything and I'm desperate.  Thank you so much for your suggestions so far, I'm feeling optimistic!

Comment: Also, looking at CodeBlocks, I can choose to compile with Cygwin GCC (I'm currently using the default, GNU GCC Compiler.  I don't know if this information is helpful but I wanted to mention it.

Comment: @user297883 Yes, running on a Linux system will make dealing with the make file easier.  GNU Make (the program that interprets a makefile) is normally distributed with a Linux system.   The readme (http://homepage.math.uiowa.edu/~dstewart/meschach/README) gives detailed instruction on building and using the Library on Linux/Unix machines (see section 4).  CodeBlocks runs on Linux just means that you would have an environment that you are familiar with versus needing to learn something new.  I think, if it were me, I go the Linux route (unless there is a compelling reason to stay on windows).

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the library into your development system.  Just *pointing* CodeBlocks to the package directory is not enough to install it.  It merely tells the compiler where to locate the header files.  You need the library modules to be compiled and linked as a library, static or dynamic.

If you cannot do this using some kind of distribution or package maintenance utility, you are going to need to recompile the library and install it yourself.  Look for instructions on the web-site on in the README file.

On a Debian Linux system, you would use `sudo apt-get install libmeschach-dev`.

On a Mac with the Macports system, you would use `sudo port install meschach`

Comment: I am using Windows 10 (Sony VAIO Ultrabook i7 processor).  Do you know what sort of "sudo" code I'd need for that?

Comment: @user297883: I don't use Windows anymore. I have no clue how to install this package on Windows, hopefully someone familiar with this platform will know and tell you.  Compiling the library might be a simple solution, but it may also be beyond your skill level.  The whole point of package managers is to remove this kind of complexity from casual users.  `sudo` is just a command to temporarily execute another one with superuser rights, a concept that may not be familiar to Windows users.

Comment: @user297883: very simply, you can thing of `sudo` as the Linux\Unix equivalent of `RunAs` on Windows (like when you right click on a file, and have the menu item "run as administrator".  Not quite the same thing, but close.